# A blank icon or space in the Menu Bar, unable to identify or remove it

Tags: menu-bar

There is an empty space in the Menu Bar. I am unable to identify what it is. I can't even remove it. I tried with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and moving it out. I have restarted my Mac. I restarted the Menu Bar with the terminal command.

[image: Screenshot of the Finder Menu Bar with a blank icon/space]

[image: Zoomed in portion of the screenshot to better shot the blank icon/space]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In the absence of an actual question, I'll go with identification:  if you have Xcode installed, Accessibility Inspector (Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector) might identify it for you, using the "target an element" crosshair tool close to the top right.

Comment: Its saying status menu

Comment: Have you noticed any app that is now missing in the status bar ? and that could have lead to this blank space ?

Comment: @kumargaurav Is there nothing under "hierarchy" at the bottom?

Comment: I am not aware of xcode at all. i just followed instructions. can you please elaborate a bit on how to check the hierarchy?

Comment: @kumargaurav Sorry for not being clearer in the first place.  If you enlarge the window shown in your screenshot, a lot more information will be displayed and at the very bottom (scroll, if necessary) the "Hierarchy" often mentions the application's name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarity. Attached screenshot with hierarchy.

Comment: Hi i just realised this is from cliptools when i saw it in detail. I imeediately uninstalled it and now issue has gone. Thanks a lot Mr. Redarm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify:
With [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) installed, "**Accessibility Inspector**" (Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Accessibility Inspector) may identify it for you, using the "**target an element**" crosshair tool close to the top right.[image: crosshair tool]

After launching the application and targeting the menu item in question with the above mentioned tool, enlarge the window (shown in your 3ʳᵈ screenshot) and a lot more information will be displayed (as shown in your last screenshot). At the very bottom (scroll, if necessary) "Hierarchy" often mentions the application's name, which in your case is "ClipTools".